# How to install Coderunner on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: ubuntu, rubygems, coderunner

I am trying to install Coderunner on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with the following guide. The system runs Ruby 2.1.0 (also tried 1.9.3 without success):

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/coderunner/index.php?title=Installing_CodeRunner#Step_1:_Configuring_your_system

Unfortunately, when I am running `$ gem install coderunner`, I get the following error-message:

```
    ➜  ~  gem install coderunner 
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing coderunner:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/test/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking gsl version... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/test/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby
extconf.rb:242:in `rescue in <main>': Check GSL>=0.9.4 is installed, and the command "gsl-config" is in search path. (RuntimeError)
    from extconf.rb:143:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/gsl-1.15.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/gsl-1.15.3/gem_make.out
```

Could you advice me how to get this fixed?

Comment: I would try reinstalling ruby1.9.1 and rubygems with apt-get, and then try to install codrunner again. Run sudo apt-get update first.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error on Ubuntu 13.10 when trying to install Coderunner.  I ran this:

```
sudo apt-get install libgsl0-dev
```

After the GSL was installed I was able to install Coderunner:

```
gem install coderunner
```

Comment: I hope this helps some people.  But I realized after installing this that I had confused this tool with the Mac tool by KrillApps.  That tool does not appear to have support for Linux.  I found this to be a suitable alternative to Codrunner for Mac http://ideone.com/